# how get the images from the flying drone to the phone or cloud

Tags: arduino, raspberry-pi, iot

we are doing a project on image processing using a camera,raspberry pi3 and a gsm module.  Above mentioned things are with a flying drone. I can send a notification message to a mobile using gsm module if required object detected on the cam. But we store that image to view on a webpage or through a mobile app easily. while it's flying it can't connect to the internet. So can you suggest a solution to get those images when it is inside our home wifi range.(any how we can get the images from sd card but i need to get those as soon as possible it detected the wifi) . Thanks in advance

Comment: Does your mobile phone have a built-in Wifi hotspot (*"Personal Hotspot"* in Apple parlance)? You could turn that on and allow your RPi to connect to it.

Comment: thanks for the reply @MarkSetchell but what will be the wifi range of it?

Comment: Outside, you are probably looking at a maximum of 300ft, but probably half that for reliable, solid, decent speed. Try it!

Comment: I'm struggled in that, after connecting to the access point (iphone) how can we get the photos?

Comment: Ensure Apache (or lighttpd) web server is running on the RPi. On the Pi, save your image to the DOCUMENT_ROOT (top-level directory) of the web server as `"image.jpg"`. On the iPhone, start Safari and go to http://IP-ADDRESS-OF-IPHONE/image.jpg and you will see the image and can save it to your Dropbox or Photos for others to see.

Comment: I am not sure if it's guaranteed, you'd have to do some tests, but my iPhone takes IP address 172.20.10.1 for itself and dishes out addresses to my RPi of 172.20.10.6. You can connect with a second iPhone and run the *"Fing"* app to see IP addresses and devices.

Comment: I have not checked, but I think you would need normally need to store your image at `/var/www/html/image.jpg` on the RPi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could consider using *"tethering"*, a.k.a. *"Personal Hotspot"* in Apple parlance, on your mobile phone.

Basically, you would enable the Personal Hotspot on your iPhone and allow your RPi to connect to it via Wifi. You would have to check your setup, but my iPhone takes IP address 172.20.10.1 for itself and dishes out IP addresses to clients which are the same but with the `1` replaced by a small number under 13.

You can see from [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/wireless-cli.md) how to setup your RPi to automagically connect to your Hotspot whenever in range. You could also consider fixing a static IP address when on that network, so you know where the RPi will show up for sure.

You would then ensure that Apache, or maybe `lighttpd` which is lighter weight, is running on your RPi.

Then, your app on the RPi would store its image as `image.jpg` in Apache's DOCUMENT_ROOT directory, probably `/var/www/html/image.jpg` but check.

Now, on the iPhone, start Safari and browse to:

```
http://172.20.10.N/image.jpg
```

where `N` is a small number. You should see your image and be able to save it to **DropBox** or **Photos** or iCloud Drive for others to see.

---

Of course, once your RPi is connected to your iPhone's hotspot, it can `FTP` or `ssh` copy the image to any website or other server on the Internet it has access to itself.

Answer (score 0):

I have understood your question also I have cheapest solution to build your project. you will be needing 3 modules

1. ESP8266 (Wifi module)
2. SD card logger
3. Camera module(go with your choice, try ESP8266(But I have not tried it))

Combining all these can get your work done. But most instructing part is `When connected with wifi it should transmit video to webpage or app and when not connected should log video to SD card`

Below is my try to solve your problem, if you have any doubts feel free to ask your question.

> ESP8266 is an WiFi module, you can connect it with an hot-spot or an router, similar to any WiFi device's on successful connection it throws 200,OK failing will throw 404 or so. Technically just like any TCP devices it will work. You can connect, disconnect, send and receive data continuously using software(using code you write).

```
0-code for camera unit starts
1-try connecting WiFi && start the camera and start logging into SD card //InCase if WiFi module takes longer time than usual to connect, this will prevent data from losing
2-if connection failed - continue writing to SD card
3-else(connection made) - start streaming the data && stop the SD card logging and save the file and create a new empty file so that we can save on next connection out without wasting data.
4-check for connection status in regular interval (goto step2).
5-on any external inputs(like click an image)
```

**most important thing**: code for your camera interface should work independent from the flight controller code. 
-NandhaFrost

Comment: Why do you suggest an ESP8266? The RPi 3 already has built-in wifi. What's an *"SD card logger"* - do you have a model/part number or link for such a thing please? And what's wrong with the SD card already in a RPi 3?

Comment: I thought that RI3 will be your dedicated flight controller. So I don't want to mess with your existing hardware. Hence, I have described in stand-alone way, if you are going to create the code and make it run along with the flight controller code, then no problem you can use the existing hardware available in RI3. Anyway, I have suggested you with an generic algorithm, please use that